# What is context variable in Airflow operators

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to understand what is this variable called context in Airflow operators.
`as example:`

```
def execute(self, **context**).
```

Where it comes from? where can I set it? when and how can I use it inside my function?
Another question is What is *context and **context?
I saw few examples that uses this variable like this:

```
def execute(self, *context) / def execute(self, **context).
```

What is the difference and when should I use *context and **context

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When Airflow runs a task, it collects several variables and passes these to the `context` argument on the `execute()` method. These variables hold information about the current task, you can find the list here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#default-variables.

Information from the context can be used in your task, for example to reference a folder `yyyymmdd`, where the date is fetched from the variable `ds_nodash`, a variable in the `context`:

```py
def do_stuff(**context):
    data_path = f"/path/to/data/{context['ds_nodash']}"
    # write file to data_path...

PythonOperator(task_id="do_stuff", python_callable=do_stuff)
```

`*context` and `**context` are different Python notations for accepting arguments in a function. Google for "args vs kwargs" to find more on this topic. Basically `*context` accepts non-keyword arguments, while `**context` takes keyword arguments:

```py
def print_context(*context_nokeywords, **context_keywords):
    print(f"Non keywords args: {context_nokeywords}")
    print(f"Keywords args: {context_keywords}")

print_context("a", "b", "c", a="1", b="2", c="3")

# Non keywords args: ('a', 'b', 'c')
# Keywords args: {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

Answer (score 16):

Documentation on the nature of `context` is pretty sparse at the moment. (There is [a long discussion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14396) in the Github repo about "making the concept less nebulous".)

In [a few](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/concepts.html#accessing-current-context) [places](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator.xcom_push) in the documentation it's referred to as a "context dictionary" or even an "execution context dictionary", but never really spelled out what that is.

[Apparently](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14396#issuecomment-962588693), the [Templates Reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) is considered to be documentation for the `context` dictionary, although that's not actually mentioned on the page.

As is often the case with Airflow, a look at the source code is sometimes our best bet. One contributor [has pointed to](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14396#issuecomment-785253467) the following [code block](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/352b970010846eb4168aa7b2e332d9a95e2facb3/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1688-L1728) to describe the `context` dict:

```py
        return {
            'conf': conf,
            'dag': task.dag,
            'dag_run': dag_run,
            'ds': ds,
            'ds_nodash': ds_nodash,
            'execution_date': pendulum.instance(self.execution_date),
            'inlets': task.inlets,
            'macros': macros,
            'next_ds': next_ds,
            'next_ds_nodash': next_ds_nodash,
            'next_execution_date': next_execution_date,
            'outlets': task.outlets,
            'params': params,
            'prev_ds': prev_ds,
            'prev_ds_nodash': prev_ds_nodash,
            'prev_execution_date': prev_execution_date,
            'prev_execution_date_success': lazy_object_proxy.Proxy(
                lambda: self.get_previous_execution_date(state=State.SUCCESS)
            ),
            'prev_start_date_success': lazy_object_proxy.Proxy(
                lambda: self.get_previous_start_date(state=State.SUCCESS)
            ),
            'run_id': run_id,
            'task': task,
            'task_instance': self,
            'task_instance_key_str': ti_key_str,
            'test_mode': self.test_mode,
            'ti': self,
            'tomorrow_ds': tomorrow_ds,
            'tomorrow_ds_nodash': tomorrow_ds_nodash,
            'ts': ts,
            'ts_nodash': ts_nodash,
            'ts_nodash_with_tz': ts_nodash_with_tz,
            'var': {
                'json': VariableJsonAccessor(),
                'value': VariableAccessor(),
            },
            'yesterday_ds': yesterday_ds,
            'yesterday_ds_nodash': yesterday_ds_nodash,
        }
```

### Update

I've since found [a mention of the context dictionary](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/taskflow.html#context) in the documentation! If anyone can find any more, I'll be happy to link them here.

> When running your callable, Airflow will pass a set of keyword arguments that can be used in your function. This set of kwargs correspond exactly to the [context variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-variables) you can use in your Jinja templates.